# Why delay in response is not working without an html tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

Below given is a sample node server code.

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080;

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
     response.write("<p>hello</p>");       //version 1
     response.write("hello");              //version 2
     setTimeout(function(){
         response.write("<p>world</p>");   //version 1
         response.write("world");          //version 2
         response.end();
     }, 2000);

}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

There are two versions of the same code. Try to run each one by one.
My confusion is with version 1 there is a delay in response as expected. And it prints

```
Hello 
(delay)
world
```

But with version 2 the output is like

```
helloworld (without delay)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's some browser-dependent behavior. You can try running `curl -N localhost:8080` (`-N` is to use non-buffered stream) and you will see that the server sends response in two parts with the delay for both versions (as you expected it to behave).

When I request the server with Chrome, it behaves as you mentioned. When I do the same in Firefox, it waits the response to fully complete before rendering the result in both cases.